# API Configuration to send data to Notion

Tags: notion-api

This is my first post so please bear with me. I am trying to insert data into a notion database. The database ID I already know. I am trying to pass a task and the text as "To Do" for a Select property titled "Kanban Status". Essentially being able to pass tasks into Notion.

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong in the below? I am getting the error -

```
{"status":400,"object":"error","code":"invalid_json","message":"Error parsing JSON body."}
```

The code is below -

```
{

"parent": { "type": "database_id", "database_id":"xyz"},

    properties: {

    "Task": {
        "type": "title",
        "title": [{ "type": "text", "text": { "content": "testing API" } }]
    }
    "Kanban status": {
        "rich_text": "text",
        "text": [{"type": "text", "text": { "content": "To Do"} }]
    }

    }
}
```

Thank you

Jerry

---

Update - Thanks to Espen for correcting a few mistakes. Now I'm seeing the below error. Any advise?

{"status":400,"object":"error","code":"validation_error","message":"body failed validation. Fix one:\nbody.properties.Kanban status.title should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.rich_text should be an array, instead was `\"text\"`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.url should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.multi_select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.people should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.email should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.phone_number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.date should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.checkbox should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.relation should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Kanban status.files should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Task.id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Task.name should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Task.start should be defined, instead was `undefined`."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem. See below what I had to fix.

```
"Kanban Status": {
    "select": {
        "name": "To Do"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put quotes around properties and a comma before "Kanban status".

```
{    
"parent": { "type": "database_id", "database_id":"xyz"},

    "properties": {

    "Task": {
        "type": "title",
        "title": [{ "type": "text", "text": { "content": "testing API" } }]
    },
    "Kanban status": {
        "rich_text": "text",
        "text": [{"type": "text", "text": { "content": "To Do"} }]
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've corrected those.